# excel protected sheet copies hidden columns

Tags: excel

i have several columns, some of which are hidden. the sheet is protected by password, and select locked cells option is unchecked.

the users that i send the file can open the workbook, and edit the unlocked cells, being unaware of whats going inside the hidden cells. they cannot unhide nor see.

however, there is a problem. if user tries to copy all the columns, and paste it in another excel sheet, all the hidden columns are shown when pasted. hence, the protection does not work.

does anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Move the hidden cells to a separate sheets, then hide that sheet?

Comment: i found a solution. excel has a flow in this topic. when the hidden columns are sandwiched between unhidden columns, excel allows one to select hidden columns, interestingly. however, if you move the columns outside the range of visible and editable columns, one cannot get access to hidden columns.

Answer (score 0):

You can't completely restrict the users from copying the data.  Because there are several methods to copy the data from your sheet.

Assume that you made column-c as hidden and protected the sheet with a password by unchecking the **Select Locked Cells** option.  Eventhough you did much protection a simple command in VBA Immediate window will get the whole column (Column-C) content.

```
range("C:C").Copy
```